# What automation tools can be used for yfile based graphs

Tags: automation, ui-automation, yfiles

I have a UI where yFiles based graphs are used.
What would be the best automation tool suitable to automate and test the same

Comment: Which platform are you interested in? [yFiles](http://www.yworks.com/products/yfiles) is available for Java Swing, JavaFX, Windows Forms, Windows WPF, HTML5, and legacy platforms like Silverlight and Adobe Flash. Different solutions exist for each of those platforms.

Answer (score 1):

yFiles for HTML can be automated using the usual tools for web UI automation with some caveats (see below). Internally we use the Selenium WebDriver API, but some other approaches work as well.

The main requirement for an automation tool is that events are reproduced faithfully like they would be by normal interaction with a browser. yFiles can be very sensitive to the correct order of input events, since we use a state machine that can get out of sync if, e.g., a mouse-down event isn't followed by a mouse-up event. Some testing approaches don't bother raising the correct events (e.g. only raising a click event while disregarding the mouse-down and -up events) and this can sometimes cause yFiles to not work as expected.